# Dismiss system alerts programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, swift

How can I dismiss system alerts which is asking for user permission of using camera, location etc programatically?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no way to dismiss them once they are displayed

Comment: I'm curious... Why would you think you ***could*** do that? The whole point of those "system alerts" is for your app to get the user's permission. If you could "dismiss them programmatically" you would be doing things the user did not authorize.